# File lost from TFS

Tags: tfs

I've got a problem with our TFS server (don't know the exact version unfortunately, but it's definitely something old).

I've checked in a changeset where among others `a.cs` is changed. Now, when looking in source control explorer `a.cs` is gone, as well as `b.cs` which wasn't in the changeset. Looking at a log the last commit is my changeset where `a.cs` is marked as "edit" - no deletion shown.

From the log details it is possible to select "view" on `a.cs` and get the up-to-date file contents, but I can't understand why it is gone from source control explorer or what to do about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible some one else deleted it.

From visual studio go to Tools | Options.  Then pick Source Control | Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.  Turn on "Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer" and see if it shows up.

Comment: Neither `a.cs` nor `b.cs` shows up at all, but I can see other old files that have been deleted. It is as if those two files have never existed.

Comment: @Anders Abel: At this point there are a couple things I would do:  First, go to another team member and see if they have the exact same problem.  If so, contact your TFS administrator and see what they can do to help.  If not, make sure you have all of the visual studio and tfs service packs applied locally.

Comment: @Anders Abel: Glad this led you to getting your source control system on a stable platform.  One of the worst things for a developer is to not be able to trust his version control system. ;)

Comment: I had a file go missing.  Not sure when or how it got deleted.  But then I did find the file in my recycle bin.  Seems hard to believe I deleted the file, but at least I found it.  Trying the show deleted files trick didn't seem to help in VS/TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found for very similar problem:

Navigate to folder containing that file in "Source Control Explorer", right click on it, select "Compare", make sure all "View options" are checked. 
Than on file list you can find your missing file. In this menu, right click option has an "Add" option available. Now file is once again tracked and you can commit changes.

For me, the problem was when file was edited by T4 process (first deleted, than created), than committed without realizing something went wrong with file states in TFS.